# Equivalent of List.exists for Db

Tags: opa

I've used List.exists(   ), i woudl like to know if there is an equivalent for Db.

If i have a function f(e) : bool, i would like to know if there is at least one element e, with f(e) -> true.
Currently i use the Db.intmap_fold_range(  ), but it iterates over all the Db, whereas it would be better for performances to stop at the first return true.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose your DB is an IntMap if you can use `Db.intmap_fold_range`.

This is a sample code :

```
// Testing function
f(key, val) = key == 42

// Check existence in "mymap"
res = IntMap.exists(f, /mymap)
```

If you look at the source code, you can see that it is implemented for folding only on  the necessary elements :) (File: [stdlib/core/map/map.opa](https://github.com/MLstate/opalang/blob/master/stdlib/core/map/map.opa))

Comment: Hi, don't you think IntMap.exists(f, /mymap) will create a new map from the Db before to perform ? I've heard that using Map functions on Db is unperformant because a new map is created each time (it's for this reason we use Db.intmap_fold_range( ))